# Creating multiple folders with dates etc. 190101 to 191231

Tags: powershell, mkdir

I'm trying to create multiple folders but for dates in a year.
Also, I have been using PowerShell and trying to create a batch script.
I had tried several solutions, but no one of them gives me what I need.
So, I need to create folders as 190101 to 191231 empty once for all year. But whatever I do I don't get what I want.

Examples:

```
01..31 | foreach $_{ New-Item -ItemType Directory -Name $("1901" + $_)}

mkdir $(01..31 | %{"ch$_"})

md(01..31|%{"1901$_"})
```

But the problem here they don't give me 0 in "days" so, I have
19011 instead of 190101.

I can't find how to extract dates and push PowerShell to create what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [format operator](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7855.using-the-f-format-operator-in-powershell.aspx) (`-f`). It was made for this exact purpose.

```
1..31 | ForEach-Object {
    New-Item -Type Directory -Name ('1901{0:d2}' -f $_)
}
```

Comment: Works as a charm. and this 0:d2 = 1 is first number and d2 (decimals ). tnx it helps !

Answer (score 4):

here is a slightly more generalized version that will work for any given month. the `-f` string format operator is really quite handy ... [*grin*]

```
$Today = (Get-Date).Date
$Year = $Today.Year
$Month = $Today.Month
$DaysInMonth = (Get-Culture).Calendar.GetDaysInMonth($Year, $Month)

foreach ($Day in 1..$DaysInMonth)
    {
    '{0}{1:D2}' -f $Today.ToString('yyMM'), $Day
    }
```

truncated output ...

```
190101
190102
[*...snip...*] 
190130
190131
```

Comment: Relevant references: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46694546/what-does-f-in-powershell-mean , https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-f-operator.html , https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7855.powershell-using-the-f-format-operator.aspx , and many others from the search https://www.google.com/search?q=powershell+format+operator

Comment: @mappetshow - you are most welcome! glad to help ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 2):

One way to create folders for every day of the **year**

- define/get the year
- set start date to Jan 1st
- to have a zero based offset get the DayOfYear for the 30th December
- use a range to AddDays to startdate and iterate

---

```
$year = (Get-Date).Year
$startdate = Get-Date -Year $year -Month 1 -Day 1
0..(Get-Date -Year $year -Month 12 -Day 30).DayOfYear| ForEach-Object{
  mkdir ($startdate.AddDays($_).ToString('yyMMdd')
)
```

Comment: Works too, thanks. One additional question, how to add subfolders here ?

Comment: Well as I see it the only answer creating folders for the whole year. Do you mean `yy\MM\dd` ? As mk dir will create intermediate folders in one step you only need to insert the backslash into the format string, but scaped with another one `mkdir ($startdate.AddDays($_).ToString('yy\\MM\\dd')`